# What is a word for "doing something to appear normal"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Such as intentionally smiling and making a movement or say something you normally would, to disguise feeling very sad or angry.

> While clenching her teeth because of the lump in her throat, she
>   ***..?..*** flicked some crumbs off the table and laughed ***...as a ?...***

Comment: You're going to need to provide more criteria for picking a word phrase. *Act*, *charade*, *front*,  *show* *bold face*, *brave face*, *public face*, *mask*: these are all possibilities. Why would one be more acceptable than another?

Answer (score 1):

**put up a facade**, or just **facade**.

Definition as per [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/facade):

> A person putting on a facade is definitely putting on a front: the face they're showing to the world doesn't match how they're feeling.

Answer (score 0):

**show**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/show)

> A false appearance; a pretense:

Answer (score 0):

To use **"camouflage"** can be used as a word for "**doing something to appear normal**". However, if you are looking for adverbs to complete the actions in your sentence, both words **"nonchalantly"** and **"casually"** work interchangeably well.

> "While clenching her teeth because of the lump in her throat, she
>   **nonchalantly** flicked some crumbs off the table and laughed **casually** as
>   a charming **camouflage**."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonchalant

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/casual

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Camoflage

If the word **"normal"** is the emphasis of your question, maybe the words **"routinely"** and **"naturally"** have better intended meaning.

> "While clenching her teeth because of the lump in her throat, she
>   **routinely** flicked some crumbs off the table and laughed **natually** as
>   a charming **camouflage**."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/routinely

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/naturally